# Linux close another app after period of user inactivity

Tags: linux

I want to close iceweasel when user inactive.
Earlier i am using "Reset kiosk" extension,but it is not compatible with "R-Kiosk" extension.
It is possibly to get inactive event via Bash?

Answer (score 0):

You can try trace running screensaver and run `killall -9 iceweasel` or give some time for user operations. Below realization of last variant:

```
#!/bin/sh

TIMELIMIT=10 #10 seconds for example
MYPROGRAMM=chromium-browser #I use chromium-browser for example
MYPID=-1

$MYPROGRAMM & MYPID=`echo $!`
sleep $TIMELIMIT
kill -9 $MYPID
zenity --info --timeout=5 --text="Session expired" #show message for user
```

Note, `zenity` can be replace with `dialog`, `gdialog` or `kdialog` in depend from your distributive.

Furthermore you can check screensaver running. It's just concept. I haven't KDE on my descktop, so you can make experiments.

```
#!/bin/sh

MYPROGRAMM=chromium-browser #I use chromium-browser for example
if [ "$(qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive)" $= 'false' ]; then
        killall -9 $MYPROGRAMM
        exit 0;
fi
```

You can try replace

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

upon

```
qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive
```

Note, it can work from (running) KDE(1).

More difficult but more reliable it parse result of `ps -C kscreenlocker` command.

---

(1)It work for me with Gnome through `qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive`

Comment: I don't think this is what the user asked. He wants the program to be closed when inactive for a certain amount of time. So, you should check the amount of activity time of the program.

Comment: 2@Claudio. Check of amount of activity time isn't trivial task. I think it need check time inside application. I have suggested other way: give time limited user session.

Comment: 2@user2409552 Script work for me. In this time I have checked it. All work correctly. Script running chromium-browser, after 10 sec. kill it and show message during 5 sec. Show your output.  Also just replace `chromium-browser` on your application. It must start for 10 sec. Or replace `kill -9  $MYPID` upon `killall -9 $MYPROGRAMM`.

Comment: 2@user2409552 I have testted it on `firefox`. It work. I think `iceweasel` must work.

Comment: I want close application when user AFK(does not use keyboard and mouse)

Comment: @user2409552, you can check screensaver in processes and kill your application if checked. But I don't know about your environment for concrete solution. I don't know what distributive you use. Or, possible, you run your application on framebuffer, not X. As variant you can modify your application for check keyboard or mouse activity.

Comment: iam using Debian 7,xorg-full,kde4.